# meaning of ",0" at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I remove the ",0" it throws error and when it is there it shows the right output. I want to know the use of it.

```
import sys
from collections import Counter
input()
socks,pairs = Counter(map(int,input().strip().split())),0
for s in socks:
     pairs = pairs + socks[s] // 2
print(pairs)
```

Comment: Please preview your question before posting. I've fixed it, but the code was not formatted readably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
socks, pairs = Counter(map(int,input().strip().split())), 0
```

translates to this:

```
(socks, pairs) = (Counter(map(int,input().strip().split())), 0)
```

It's as if you wrote :

```
socks = Counter(map(int,input().strip().split()))
pairs = 0
```

The difference being right side is fully evaluated before assignments, but it doesn't matter here

But the sizes of tuples must match. When you omit `,0` it becomes:

```
(socks, pairs) = (Counter(map(int,input().strip().split())), )
```

As you can see, the sizes don't match. This is what causes the problem.

Comment: Not always. Because `a, b = a+b, a` is different from `a = a+b; b = a`.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning to two variables (`socks` and `pairs`) in this line:

```
socks,pairs = Counter(map(int,input().strip().split())),0
```

If you omit `,0`, it's like writing:

```
socks = Counter(map(int,input().strip().split()))
pairs =
```

Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a tuple assignment. for example, if you want to initiate two variables x and y and assign two values a and b for them you can do it with like:

```
x = a
y = b
```

or just:

```
x, y = a, b
```

in this case, the first value 'a' will be assigned to the first variable 'x' and the second value 'b' will be assigned to the second variable 'y'. In this is very powerful to swap two values without using a temp variable as follows:
    x, y = y, x

in your case you are initiating two variables: socks and pairs so they must be followed by two values. In your case:

```
socks = Counter(map(int, input().strip().split()))
pairs = 0
```

So, it's pretty obvious that you can't assign one value to two variables. so you can't remove the 0 (pairs initial value) which is a reserved variable to accumulate on it while looping.